# c# DirectoryInfo and Except

Tags: c#

I perform the following code and the result is puzzling me

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDir = 
      new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"\\share\data");

// AllDir  == 10 folders

System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] AllDir = 
      rootDir.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

// JackDir  == 2 folders

System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] JackDir = 
      rootDir.GetDirectories("Jack*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

// MaryDir == 3 folders

System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] MaryDir = 
      rootDir.GetDirectories("Mary*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] otherDirectory = 
      AllDir.Except<DirectoryInfo>(MaryDir).Except(JackDir).ToArray();
```

And `otherDirectory` in the end still has 10 folders...why not 5? How can I achieve this?

Comment: I imagine this is because `Except` compares references and items in `MaryDir` aren't references to any objects in `AllDir`.

Comment: and when you try this :`System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] otherDirectory = 
      AllDir.Except(MaryDir).Except(JackDir).ToArray();`? what is the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing `DirectoryInfo` instances. They are not the same as they are returned by different calls to `GetDirectories`.

You can define your own comparer for `DirectoryInfo` comparing `FullName` and use it in your calls to `Except`.

```
public class DirectoryInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<System.IO.DirectoryInfo>
{
  public bool Equals(System.IO.DirectoryInfo x, System.IO.DirectoryInfo y)
  {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;
    if (x == null || y == null)
      return false;
    return x.FullName == y.FullName;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(System.IO.DirectoryInfo obj)
  {
    if (obj == null)
      return 0;
    return obj.FullName.GetHashCode();
  }
}


System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] otherDirectory = 
      AllDir.Except<DirectoryInfo>(MaryDir, new DirectoryInfoComparer()).Except(JackDir, new DirectoryInfoComparer()).ToArray();
```

Comment: using `Name` is error prone, they may be true even when the directories are not same :) use `FullName` instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a custom comparer, You see this behavior because it is tested equality against "Reference comparison" and of course they are different references.

Use Except method overload which takes `IEqualityComparer` as parameter to achieve the desired output.